# iOS10: tapping an action from local notification does not bring app to the foreground

Tags: notifications, ios10, swift2

I am trying to implement the action from notification. And so far I am able to trigger the right delegate functions, but after tapping the app is not brought to the foreground.

Relevant code:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func registerCategory() -> Void{
    print("register category")
    let callNow = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "call", title: "Call now", options: [])
    let clear = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "clear", title: "Clear", options: [])
    let category : UNNotificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory.init(identifier: "IDENT123", actions: [callNow, clear], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func scheduleNotification(event : String, interval: NSTimeInterval) {

    print("schedule ", event)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = event
    content.body = "body"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "CALLINNOTIFICATION"
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
    let identifier = "id_"+event
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
    center.addNotificationRequest(request) { (error) in

    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    print("willPresent")
    completionHandler([.Badge, .Alert, .Sound])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    let notification: UNNotification = response.notification
    let UUID = notification.request.content.userInfo["UUID"] as! String

    switch (response.actionIdentifier) {
    case "COMPLETE":

        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers([UUID])

    case "CALLIN":

        let call = Call()

        CalendarController.sharedInstance.fetchMeetingByUUID(UUID, completion: { (thisMeeting) -> Void in
            if(!CallIn.Yield(thisMeeting).ConferenceCallNumber.containsString("None")){
                call._call(thisMeeting)
            }else{
                //will open detail view, in case that no number were detected
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OpenDetailViewOfMeeting", object: self, userInfo: ["UUID":UUID])
            }
        })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers([UUID])
    default: // switch statements must be exhaustive - this condition should never be met
        log.error("Error: unexpected notification action identifier: \(UUID)")
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

I am able to hit the delegate function didReceiveNotificationResponse() with a breakpoint, and it does some actions that I put there, but not in a way that is expected (It has to  start a device-call, instead it just dismisses notifications list, and nothing happens, however when I manually open the app again, the call starts as if there is no permission to open the app from notification).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out the reason myself, so this might be helpful to someone in the future. The answer turned out to be quite simple. When creating an action of the notification, there is this parameter: options. When you register category, you need to put it either way .Foreground or .Destructive like this:

```
func reisterCategory () {
    let callNow = UNNotificationAction(identifier: NotificationActions.callNow.rawValue, title: "Call now", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.Foreground)
    let clear = UNNotificationAction(identifier: NotificationActions.clear.rawValue, title: "Clear", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.Destructive)
    let category = UNNotificationCategory.init(identifier: "NOTIFICATION", actions: [callNow, clear], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])
}
```